# Merging two projects STM32 by cmake

Tags: cmake, stm32, bootloader

I have two projects in VSCode for STM32 bootloader and main application. Both projects use cmake+ninja. Just for fun, I want to combine them into one executable so that I can just load one hex file into the controller and that's it. In theory, this can be done using cmake, but I have little experience working with it. Please tell me where to dig.

From what I googled there was a proposal to link object files from each project. But I don't understand how to do it yet